# datatable search by clicking dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to search for the band in the datatables by clicking on the band (`.search` class)

```html
@foreach($bands as $band)
    <tr>    
        <td class="bg-info">
             <div class="search"><a href="">{{$band->name}}</a></div>
       </td>
       <td class="bg-info">
            <b>{{$band->views}}</b>
       </td>
    </tr>   
@endforeach
```

I'm searching in table with id featured. i.e. `#featured`

```
$(document).on('click','.search', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $(this).val();
    #featured.search(search).draw();   
});
```

But, while i click on any band i got MethodNotAllowed exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic to achieve this isn't quite right. You need to call `search()` on the DataTable itself, not on a jQuery object (or a string as in your original example). Then the value of the search term is coming from the text of the `a` element within the `.search` div. Try this:

```
var dt = $('#yourTable').DataTable();

$(document).on('click', '.search a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dt.search($(this).text().trim()).draw();   
});
```